# Android Studio calculation circles

Tags: android, android-studio, geometry

I am trying to write an app, which allows you to calculate a circle. I made a main layout and a second layout. Main  layout: activity_main
                 second layout: kreislay

Don't wonder about those strange words, I'm a german.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public Button kreisd;
public Button kugeld;
public Button kreiscalc;

public Context con;

public EditText radius_eingabe = null;

public TextView kreis_ergebnis_vol;
public TextView kreis_ergebnis_G;

public String str1;

public double st1;
public double G_kreis;
public static final double PI = 3.141592653589793d;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    final LayoutInflater factory_main = getLayoutInflater();
    final View view2 = factory.inflate(R.layout.kreislay, null);
    final View main_view = factory_main.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    kreisd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kreis);
    kugeld = (Button)main_view.findViewById(R.id.kugel);



    kreiscalc = (Button)view2.findViewById(R.id.calc_kreis);

    kreisd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            con = MainActivity.this;
            setContentView(R.layout.kreislay);
        }
    });

    kreiscalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            con = MainActivity.this;


            radius_eingabe = (EditText) view2.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            str1 = radius_eingabe.getText().toString();
            st1 = Double.parseDouble(str1);
            G_kreis = PI*st1*st1;
            kreis_ergebnis_G = (TextView)view2.findViewById(R.id.G_kreis);
            kreis_ergebnis_G.setText(String.valueOf(G_kreis));



        }
    });


}
```

My problem is, that it is not working. When i hit the button to calculate the circle, just nothing happens, although I entered a radius. There is NO error code in LogCat. I Need help. I mean, the Area of a circle is = Pi*r^2, isn't it? 
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: is that event listener firing? have you tried debugging the value of "G_kreis"

Comment: Yes! I am running in debug mode..doesn't say anything

Comment: what is the value of G_kreis after your operations? null?  What is the value of st1?

Comment: Got it! The Problem was the onClickListener.. I made a different method ( XML onClick ), now it works

Answer (score -2):

maybe this?

```
public static final double PI = 3.141592653589793d;
```

The "d" at the end is wrong I think.
Hope it helps